# Issues with continuously nesting while loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm writing a text-based RPG in python 3. I'm writing it with individual scenes that will execute related functions based on user input in that specific scene. Some of those inputs will move the user to a new scene. The player is stuck in a scene with a while True loop until they move to a new scene, where they are once again stuck in a while True loop. This hasn't been a problem, but I'm a novice I would just like to know if this could cause issues down the line since the game will essentially be running on infinitely nested while loops.

Below is how I'm getting inputs from players and using them to execute commands based on where the player is.  Note my code structure isn't quite like this, I'm using classes and storing available commands differently, but I wanted a simple way to show how the scene changing works. My question only pertains to the while loops. Thanks so much!

```
def scene_room():
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == "go outside":
            scene_outside()
        elif user_input == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")

def scene_outside():
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == "go room":
            scene_room()
        elif user_input == "info":
            print("You're outside.")
        elif user_input == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid command")

scene_room()
```

Comment: Yes this is problematic, but not because of the `while True`s. You have mutual recursion between the two functions. If the user goes outside, then to the room, then back outside 500-1000 times, your program will crash. While that may be unlikely to happen, it's not a good design to reinforce.

Comment: Yes, there is a limited stack size. So you can only run a finite number of functions at the same time. For this purpose the limit is probably high enough that you are unlikely to reach it, but it's there is if you get a stack overflow there is no way to catch and recover

Comment: You'll have to be exceptionally careful with `While True` since it's inherently "blocking" in nature, which means your program can't do anything else while the loop is running. This is particularly a concern when running a GUI framework, where you'll most likely end up blocking the UI thread and causing your program to hang, but generally best to avoid altogether!

Comment: The design you are looking for is a state machine, where a function takes the current room and a direction as input and returns the new room. Another function handles whatever happens *in* the room before returning control to the function for moving from one room to another. (The other problem with mutual recursion is that calling `scene_room`, then `scene_outside`, then `scene_room` again is *not* the same as the original call to `scene_outside `actually returning. What you have is similar to continuation-passing style, where you *never* expect any of your functions to actually return.)

Comment: One technique for converting your recursive design to an iterative approach is to use a [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the answer is yes, nesting while loops can cause issues by both exceeding the limited stack size and because while loops are generally "blocking" in nature (which I don't fully understand, but I'm including this for people that will). In this specific case, there is also the issue of possibly infinite recursion because the functions are also nesting.

A solution to the code I provided is to return the new scene without calling it from within the while loop or function. We need a wrapper function to handle calling new scenes so that we can exit each scene function before calling a new one.

```
def scene_room():
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == "go outside":
            return scene_outside # break loop before calling
        elif user_input == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")

def scene_outside():
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == "go room":
            return scene_room # # break loop before calling
        elif user_input == "info":
            print("You're outside.") # not new scene so stay in loop
        elif user_input == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid command")

def play():
    new_scene = scene_room
    while True:
        new_scene = new_scene()
```